# How to update Android TextView element every N seconds N times from activity?

Tags: android

I need to update TextView from activity every 2 seconds 5 times. I tried postDelayed() and other stuff and I managed to change TextView every N seconds but I don't know how to limit number of repetition. Any suggestions? 
Thank you!

Here is code I have for now:

onCreate():

```
Timer timing = new Timer();
timing.schedule(new Updater(textView, textView2), 3000, 3000);
```

Updater():

```
  private static class Updater extends TimerTask {
        final Random rand = new Random();
        private final TextView textView1;
        private final TextView textView2;

        public Updater(TextView textView1, TextView textView2) {
            this.textView1 = textView1;
            this.textView2 = textView2;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView1.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    textView1.setText(String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(50) + 1));
                    textView2.setText(String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(50) + 1));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use CountDownTimer that is packed with Android SDK:

```
    new CountDownTimer(TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME_IN_MILLIS, TICK_TIME) 
    {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() 
        {
            mTextField.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
```

So in your case TICK_TIME should be 2 * 1000, TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME should be 5 * 2 * 1000. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep a counter in your activity: `int numberOfUpdates = 0;`
2. Create a recursive method checking the counter:

   ```
   public void updateTextView()
   {
       if(numberOfUpdates < 5)
       {
           numberOfUpdates++;
           textview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run ()
               {
                   updateTextView();
               }
           }, 3000);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Where should I put that counter? Probably it should not be inside onCreate() method since the method is executed before showing anything on screen, as far as I know. Thanks!

Comment: You should put this int numberOfUpdates = 0; as a class variable so that your method updateTextView() can access it.